# Simply display 3 most recent posts with title/timestamp/category/teaser/link

Tags: php, wordpress, posts

I am trying to simply display the three most recent posts. The original method only lets me display a list of linked titles and I don't want to install a heavy plugin to just get something so simple to work. I know that the following code is not working, it is more a visualization of what I want to achieve. If I remove `Line 7`, `9`, `10` and `12`, the code works, just that it doesn't display enough of what I want to have displayed.

Thank you for your assistance!

(a search on Stackoverflow didn't bring up any solutions...)

```
<?php
   $args = array( 'numberposts' => '3' );
   $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
   foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
     echo '<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">

       <h3>'. apply_filters('the_title', get_post_field('post_title', $recent["ID"])) .'</h3>

       <p class="timestamp">'. get_the_time("j. F Y", $recent["ID"]) . '</p> 
       <p class="category">'. foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { echo $category->cat_name; } .'</p>'.

       get_the_content(" ...", $recent["ID") 

       .'<p><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" class="btn" role="button">Weiterlesen</a></p></div>';

   }
   wp_reset_query();
?>
```

EDIT: I have updated the code for the titles. Now links and titles work, time stamps, categories and excerpts don't work.

Comment: Update: I resolved the problem at least for the posts' titles with `apply_filters('the_title', get_post_field('post_title', $recent["ID"]))`. This also works with the posts' contents, but it doesn't constrain the content in any way that it would work as a teaser. For the posts' categories and time stamps I can't find any lead...

Comment: Update 2: I resolved now also the timestamps with quite an inception-like code: `date_i18n("j. F Y",strtotime(apply_filters('the_time', get_post_field('post_date', $recent["ID"]))))`This will retrieve the unix time stamp off of the database field for the post, convert it into a nicer looking human-readable appearance and finally resolve the '1970'-issue. Nice to see that something things actually work out. I am coming closer to the full solution of the problem. :-)

Comment: Have you considered using WP_Query directly to just query the for the posts you need, rather than trying to get this to work with filters? `wp_get_recent_posts` uses WP_Query itself.

Comment: I have what I wanted now, wp_query seemed like opening up a whole new pot of problems while wp_get_recent_posts was far to slim.

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to use functions that are only meant for used in the Wordpress Loop, and you are trying to get around that in what looks like a very complicated way by using filters etc - you should really try to simplify even without the use of WP_Query. I also see that you still don't have the categories in your solution.

Comment: Ha! You're right, it was actually quite simple. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you got sorted. You might want to post the solution you found, to help anyone else with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Working code. Important is to open and reset WP_Query at the beginning and the end, the rest inside is standard procedure.

```
<div class="row">
  <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=3' ); ?>

  <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>

    <div <?php post_class('col-lg-4 col-md-6'); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
      <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
      <p class="category"><?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { echo $category->cat_name; } ?></p>
      <p class="timestamp"><?php the_time('j. F Y') ?></p>
      <?php the_content(' ...'); ?>
      <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="btn" role="button">Weiterlesen</a></p>
    </div>

  <?php
  endwhile;
  wp_reset_postdata();
  ?>
</div>
```

Comment: This is all that `wp_get_recent_posts` was doing anyway, because it just calls `WP_Query`. This way you skip the step that complicated the issue and go straight to the source - it makes life a lot easier for yourself :)